# How to remove Calendars from Gnome Calendar?

Tags: 17.10, calendar, online-accounts

I have removed Google from my *Online Accounts*. But when I start my computer I am asked for a Google password. The dialog does not show which application is asking. I suppose it is Calendar.

When I start Calendar and go to *Calendars* in the menu, there are still multiple Google calenders in the list? How do I remove these calendars?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was no longer using Evolution anyway so I was able to remove the config files for evolution and when I logged out and back in the accounts were gone. If you still use Evolution that probably won't work for you though. 
removed ~/.config/evolution/ and ~/.local/share/evolution/

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.config/evolution/sources/; killall gnome-calendar`

Answer (score 5):

In 18.04.1 it is still enough to make the command

```
rm ~/.config/evolution/sources/*
```