# Another country calendar

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, screenshot, calendar

let me start off by saying I don't know what I'm doing. It took me time to get the Num Lock to come on on bootup on computer.

Num Lock was on in Bios, I loaded if I remember right NumlockX and copied lots bit of code from websites and edited files·

Anyway to the point I don't know how but I have calendar from another country I still have a UK calendar. I right click and exit other calendar, on reboot or next day it's come back.

I look to remove but only shows UK calendar also looked at languages again only English.
Don't really want copy and past more code in and make things worst added link below.

Would the best thing to do is just reload Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4 LTS
I have added screenshots of calendar

Thanks

Screenshot 1

[image: screenshot]

Screenshot 2

[image: screenshot]

[How to remove Calendars from Gnome Calendar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971970/how-to-remove-calendars-from-gnome-calendar)[bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JABGj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The calendar shown on your screenshots is created by `hijra-applet`.

If you want to remove it - use

```
sudo apt-get remove hijra-applet
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you for help N0rbert. Is that sometime that I would have added? Don't know how.

Comment: My answers show the commands to remove Hijra calendar. I do not really know how you have added it first time.

Comment: Many thanks N0rbert
My times off going look at YouTube see if I can lean how my way round Linuxs